# Lan Messenger WPF or WCF?

Tags: c#

I want to create a lan messenger in c#, I don't know what I use in WPF or WCF.
I want to know which is the best for creating the program?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'best'? Have you done any research? Can you share details?

Comment: And do You know what WPF and WCF  stand for and what they are? Maybe you should try reading about them first?

Comment: You need to do your own research, WPF and WCF are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the right question. WPF is a framework for creating guis, while WCF is a framework for communication. You'll probably need both.

Options for GUI (some):

- WPF
- WinForms (older, but simpler for begginers)
- etc.

Options for Communication:

- WCF
- Direct implementation of sockets
- .NET remoting (a bit outdated)
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are choosing between those, your choice looks strange: these are completely different technologies. WCF is used for communication, WPF for UI. People frequently use both of them together. For messenger it looks appropriate to use both.